# How to add sum of columns in datagridview with datasource

Tags: c#

How would i add a a row to the bottom of this datagridview with a sum all the above rows. The rows are bound from a datatable.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value);
    DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(sum);
}
```

I have tried to ;ppl at DataGridView1.Rows.Insert and .Add but am unsure how i would be best to do this.

Answer (score 1):

try to add footer as

```
 DataGridView1["Sum", dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Value = sum;
```

or try this one.

```
    void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        double sum=0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            sum+= Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value);
        }
        var newrowindex= dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        DataGridViewRow summaryRow = dataGridView1.Rows[newrowindex];
        summaryRow.Cells[col].Value =sum;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

**CS**

```
private double _total;
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Row.RowType)
    {
        case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
            _total+=//increse the total
        break
        case DataControlRowType.Footer:
            //Put the total in the right cell of the footer
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text=_total.ToString();
        break;
    }
}
```

**Markup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" ShowFooter="True" runat="server">

</asp:GridView>
```